# How Can I Find Compile-Time Errors in MVC Razor Views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When I make a change to a model that is used by several views, but neglect to update one or more views to reflect the changes, the problem only becomes apparent when I actually browse to the affected view thus triggering runtime compilation.

How can I find such errors at compile time in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 6):

By default MVC views are compiled at runtime.  To cause them to be compiled at build time instead:

- Edit the project file in a text editor
- Change the line `<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>` to read `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>`
- Save the edits and allow Visual Studio (if running) to reload the project file when prompted.

Building will take slightly longer.  However, on my (fast) system with a medium-size project I hardly notice the difference.